# Handle imports that must be changed in many classes

Tags: java

In my application Java classes communicate with Cobol through some jars. I call them using imports that refer to the jar inner classes (where is specified the version). Eg.:

```
import com.dsi.business.SSA_YU.integration.jdo.P_YUCCS00.C_YUCCS00;
import com.dsi.business.SSA_YU.integration.jdo.P_YUCCS00.INHEADER;
import com.dsi.business.SSA_YU.integration.jdo.P_YUCCS00.INPBST;
```

That is used, then, in methods (other point where I have to change the version everytime):

```
public void doSomething(int param1, C_YUCCS00 msg) {
...
}
```

My problem is: each of these jars is imported in MANY Java classes (100-150, for example). If the version of the "jar" (actually it's the name of the inner classes) changes I will have to import the new jar and, so, to adjust the imports like this:

```
import com.dsi.business.SSA_YU.integration.jdo.P_YUCCS01.C_YUCCS01;
import com.dsi.business.SSA_YU.integration.jdo.P_YUCCS01.INHEADER;
import com.dsi.business.SSA_YU.integration.jdo.P_YUCCS01.INPBST;
```

That means doing a lot of changes and version a lot of classes.

Do you know if there's a way to solve this? There is a way to put the imports in one separated Java class to use only for imports and call that one?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Create abstraction layer. Specify your own interface (set of interfaces) to external jar. Whole your program should use that interface. When you get new jar you need only change one file with implementation.

Comment: So I put the import in an interface...only the import? Because then when I call the jar in the "original" classes, I am not able to create the "C_YUCCS00 msg" variable (for example). But maybe I should declare a variable inside the interface? I hope I've explained myself...

Comment: I tried right now creating an abstract class with the include and a variable C_YUZLS09 yuzl. In the original class I just have the problem that, in methods, I still have to specify the type, and so the version (eg. public void doSomething(int param1, C_YUCCS00 msg)). Am I going into the right direction?

Comment: This might be beside the point but why are the classes being renamed for each version, why not rename the jar instead for each version and keep the class names the same?

Comment: The jar structure is created automatically by a tool that is managed by another office, unfortunately I can't edit that. If I could I would do exactly as you suggest!

Comment: How are you getting access the objects of those classes? Are they sent/returned from some api or do you call `new` on them or create them with some factory class/method in your code?

Comment: When the class implements an unversioned interface, look with 7zip or such in the jar. IF thoughtfully created using the java SPI (service provider interface) then there should be a META-INF/services/`class-path-of-interface` text files, and you can use SPI.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I am getting access to the objects calling a new on them and then accessing to the fields directly (eg.: C_YUCCS00 yucc = new... and then -> yucc.INPUT = ....)

Comment: @JoopEggen In the META-INF I just hav  the manifest.xml :( Unfortunately

Comment: @Pipkin was almost to be expected, but Java SPI allows differently named classes to implement one interface, and be detected on run-time. So one should take a look at such possibilities.

Comment: @JoopEggen I used another simpler solution but I read about Java SPI and seems to be very useful. I will study about this, thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use proxy classes that contains a versioned class and has the same public methods as the underlying versioned classes. Then each proxy class is used in your part of the code instead of the versioned class. One part that is not clear is how to initialize a proxy class since it is not clear from the question how this interaction between the versioned classes and the application classes takes place

```
import com.dsi.business.SSA_YU.integration.jdo.P_YUCCS00.C_YUCCS00;

public class C_YUCCProxy {
    private  C_YUCCS00 underlying;

    //First example of constructor if new objects are created
    public C_YUCCProxy() {
         this.underlying = new C_YUCCS00();
    }

    //Second example using existing object
    public C_YUCCProxy(C_YUCCS00 object) {
         this.underlying = object;
    }

    public void doLogic(int value) {
        underlying.doLogic(value);
    }

    public String getStringValue() {
        return underlying.getStringValue();
    }
    //... all other public methods
}
```

---

And then in other part of the application code

```
public void doSomething(int param1, C_YUCCProxy msg) { 

     msg.doLogic(42);
     String response = msg.getStringValue();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Joakim, I'm going to try this soon and let you know

Comment: I used your solution creating the C_YUCCProxy with a new(). I did it!!! Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

*If more classes and packages are involved:*

You might be best off, writing your own ClassLoader that does renaming from packages and class names to more general names. Probably combined with a byte code library, like ASM.

Or you might use a byte code library, like ASM, to convert the generated library entirely.
Which is a bit more work.

Comment: I used a simpler solution (for my knowledge) but...I didn't know about the ClassLoader, I'm going to study about this. It can be very useful for many things! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use Eclipse for IDE, use its global (across source files) text search and replace to replace all appearances of, say, "_YUCCS00" with, say, "_YUCCS01".

Then deal with any errors one by one.  (There will be errors if the version transition has breeches of backward compatibility [in the functions you are actively using] - but note that such errors will also manifest themselves if you opt for any of the other solutions and possibly will only manifest themselves at run time.)

You might still have to repeat this action per application that is impacted, but at least it's no longer "repeat per class".

What you *really* need to do is force that other team to stop their crappy way of releasing versions.  It betrays a high level of "we consider only our own interests" kind of attitude [and hence a total lack of consideration of the user's (you) interests, which is kind of odd for a team publishing a library jar].  You do this by showing to management what the cost is that other team is causing by sticking to it.

Comment: I totally agree about that, things had to be structured in a more intelligent way at the beginning...right now changing it would have a big impact on the way also the other offices implement that. I hope things will change in the future...meanwhile thank you for the Eclipse tip :)